# Typecasting derived class as base class leads to a base class member function call

Tags: c++, inheritance

In a situation when a base class and a derived class have an identically named member function, why does type casting the derived class as a base class and calling the member actually produce output corresponding to the base class? I thought the member function definition in the derived class overwrote the function in the base class.

In the code below, there is a base class `myClass` and a derived class `newClass`. Both `myClass` and `newClass` implement a member function called `serialize().`

When the instance `insta` of type `newClass` is typecast as `myClass`, the `serialize()` member function that is called belongs to the base class `myClass` and not the derived class. The addresses are the same for both calls, which indicates that there is no mysterious copying event that is happening, and that this is indeed  something to do with type casting.

Why does this happen?

Here is the code that reproduces this behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class myClass{

friend void Inspect(myClass&);
private:
    int data;
    std::string name;
public:
    myClass(std::string _name, int _d):
        name(_name),
        data(_d){}
    std::vector<double> v;
    std::string serialize();

};


std::string myClass::serialize(){
    std::ostringstream retstream;
    retstream << "string name " << name << "\n";
    retstream << "int data " << data << "\n";
    retstream << "vector<double> v ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        retstream << v[i] << " ";
    }
    retstream << "\n";
    retstream << "---" << std::endl;
    retstream << "address " << this << "\n";
    return retstream.str();
}

class newClass: public myClass{

private:
    int data2;
    std::string name;
public:
    newClass(std::string _name, int _d):
        myClass(_name, _d), name(_name), data2(_d){}
    std::string serialize();
};


std::string newClass::serialize(){
    std::ostringstream retstream;
    retstream << "string name " << name << "\n";
    retstream << "address " << this << "\n";
    return retstream.str();
}


template <class T>
void Inspect(T & instance){
//#if defined(DDEBUG) || defined(DDDEBUG)
    std::cout << "Inspecting " << typeid(instance).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << instance.serialize() << "\n";
    std::cout << &instance << "\n";
//#endif
}


int main(){
newClass insta("newClass_instance-1", 2);
Inspect<myClass>(insta);
Inspect<newClass>(insta);
return 0;}
```

On compiling this code and running it, one gets this output:

```
Inspecting 7myClass
string name newClass_instance-1
int data 2
vector<double> v 
---
address 0x7fff73529fb0

0x7fff73529fb0
Inspecting 8newClass
string name newClass_instance-1
address 0x7fff73529fb0

0x7fff73529fb0
```

My compiler information is `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`

Comment: Because the member function is not `virtual`.

Comment: So this is not a quirk of my compiler and this behavior will persist across different systems?

Comment: Specifically, C++ member functions are not polymorphic by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the member as virtual.  Declaring a member as virtual adds a hidden vtable object to your class.  The vtable is basically an array of pointers to functions (each compiler will implement this differently).  When you call a virtual function, the vtable is used to call the function.  When you call a non virtual class function, the type of the class is used to call the function.

```
class Base {
  virtual void VirtualFunc() { }
  void Func() { }
};
class Derived : public Base {
  void VirtualFunc() override { }
  void Func() override { }
};

Base* pBase = new Base();

pBase->VirtualFunc();                       // calls Base's VirtualFunc
((Derived*)pBase)->VirtualFunc();           // calls Base's VirtualFunc
pBase->Derived::VirtualFunc();              // wont compile
((Derived*)pBase)->Derived::VirtualFunc();  // will crash
pBase->Func();                              // calls Base's Func
((Derived*)pBase)->Func();                  // will crash

Derived* pDerived = new Derived();

pDerived->VirtualFunc();                    // calls Derived's VirtualFunc
((Base*)pDerived)->VirtualFunc();           // calls Derived's VirtualFunc
pDerived->Base::VirtualFunc();              // calls Base's VirtualFunc
((Base*)pDerived)->Base::VirtualFunc();     // calls Base's VirtualFunc
pDerived->Func();                           // calls Derived's Func
((Base*)pDerived)->Func();                  // calls Base's Func
```